# Are there any cons to buying a used iPhone 4S unlocked by a Gevey sim?

Tags: iphone, unlock, sim

In comparison to a factory unlocked iPhone, are there any cons to buying a used iPhone 4S unlocked by a Gevey sim?

Answer (score 2):

The big downside is that the phone isn't really unlocked.

Apple could patch the exploit that allows it to work in a firmware update. Also, you may have to re-unlock it every time you power off your phone or lose signal for more than a couple of seconds. Some people also report poor signal and battery performance with it. Theres some more info [here](http://jaxov.com/2011/03/what-is-gevey-sim-hack-and-how-gevey-sim-interposer-work-to-unlock-iphone-4/) or just google "disadvantages of Gevey Sim."